# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "django_admin_log" does not exist

Tags: python, django, windows, powershell, terminal

I just started learning Django, and I'm following a book as guide (the book is from August 2022, so new) and I ran into 2 problems.

The first one was that Python couldn't find the module `psycopg2` which I then installed. Now I'm a little further and created my first model and migrated it to the database, which all seemed to work well. I then created a superuser and opened localhost:8000/admin/ and it sent me to the admin site, I logged in with my newly created user, so far so good. Now the problem.

This is what the site shows me:
[image]

And this is what the log says:
[image]

I've tried many approaches I found on here, for example deleted the migrations folder in my applications folder and then migrated my application again. I'll just go through a few other commands I've tried:

```
>> python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb admin
#CommandError: Can't use run_syncdb with app 'admin' as it has migrations.
>> python manage.py sqlmigrate admin 0001
# response: [The SQL query...]
>> python manage.py syncdb
# response: Unknown command: 'syncdb'
>> python manage.py migrate --fake
#Operations to perform:
#  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions
#Running migrations:      
#  No migrations to apply.
```

This is what the database looks like right now

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself on https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/14632/

I first ran the command `python manage.py migrate admin zero --fake`, and then migrated again with `python manage.py migrate`, then ran the server and now the error is gone!